# Mapbox Tile Source issue while internet is off

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm working on an offline map. I updated **Mapbox SDK 6.2 to 10.7** Style pack and tile region are downloading successfully.

Step 1 - Download the style and a tile source on the home screen

Step 2 - Turn off the internet

Step 3 - Navigate to the home screen

**Actual Result:**

Mapbox map is displayed but road, street etc. details are missing while the internet is off.

**Expected result:**

Mapbox map should display roads, streets and other details while the internet is off.

I appreciated your help resolve this issue. thanks

*Here, is the code for downloading the tile region and style pack*

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        // 1. Create style package with loadStylePack() call.
        let stylePackLoadOptions = StylePackLoadOptions(glyphsRasterizationMode: .ideographsRasterizedLocally,
                                                        metadata: ["tag": "my-outdoors-style-pack"],
                                                        acceptExpired: true)!
let tileStore = TileStore.default
    let accessToken = ResourceOptionsManager.default.resourceOptions.accessToken
    tileStore.setOptionForKey(TileStoreOptions.mapboxAccessToken, value: accessToken)
    self.tileStore = tileStore
        let accessToken = ResourceOptionsManager.default.resourceOptions.accessToken
        offlineManager = OfflineManager(resourceOptions: ResourceOptions(accessToken: accessToken, tileStore: tileStore))

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        _ = offlineManager?.loadStylePack(for: .outdoors, loadOptions: stylePackLoadOptions) { [weak self] progress in
            // These closures do not get called from the main thread. In this case
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(" progress completedResourceCount/ - requiredResourceCount \(progress.completedResourceCount) / \(progress.requiredResourceCount)")
                print("StylePack = \(progress)")
            }

        } completion: { [weak self] result in
            // getting result success
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                defer {
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }

                switch result {
                case let .success(stylePack):
                    print("StylePack = \(stylePack)")

                case let .failure(error):
                    print("stylePack download Error = \(error)")
                }
            }
        }

        // 2. Create an offline region with tiles for the outdoors style
        let outdoorsOptions = TilesetDescriptorOptions(styleURI: .outdoors, zoomRange: UInt8(minZoom)...UInt8(maxZoom))
        guard let outdoorsDescriptor = offlineManager?.createTilesetDescriptor(for: outdoorsOptions) else {
            print("outdoorsDescriptor -> missing")
            return
        }
        // Load the tile region
        let tileRegionLoadOptions = TileRegionLoadOptions(
            geometry: .point(Point(coord)),
            descriptors: [outdoorsDescriptor],
            metadata: userInfo,
            acceptExpired: true)!

        // Use the the default TileStore to load this region. You can create
        // custom TileStores are are unique for a particular file path, i.e.
        // there is only ever one TileStore per unique path.
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        _ = tileStore.loadTileRegion(forId: tileRegionId, loadOptions: tileRegionLoadOptions) { progress in
            // These closures do not get called from the main thread. In this case
            // we're updating the UI, so it's important to dispatch to the main
            // queue.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update the progress bar
                print("Download progress : ")
                print(Float(progress.completedResourceCount) / Float(progress.requiredResourceCount))
            }
        } completion: { result in
            //getting result success
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                defer {
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }

                switch result {
                case let .success(tileRegion):
                    print("tileRegion = \(tileRegion)")

                    print(" tileRegion progress completedResourceCount/ - requiredResourceCount \(tileRegion.completedResourceCount) / \(tileRegion.requiredResourceCount)")

                case let .failure(error):
                    print("tileRegion download Error = \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        // Wait for both downloads before moving to the next state
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("notify download complete")
        }
```

Added map here:

```
let mapView = MapView(frame: view.bounds)
mapView.mapboxMap.loadStyleURI(.outdoors)
self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

result i'm getting before turning on mobile data:
[image: before turning on mobile data]

after turning on mobile data
[image: after turning on mobile data]

Comment: Did you ever find out why it wasn't showing up?